# How to simulate a sign language keyboard in IOS?

Tags: fonts, keyboard, sign

I'm trying to develop an app similar to this [one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sign-language-email-keyboard/id314603243?mt=8) :

[image]

I was able to use custom font, but what if the letter are images and not a font file? Any how can I send it as an email for exemple?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you're using a font or images? I'm confused.

Comment: I need any working solution, for now it's images. But I think there is a way to convert images to font if needed.