# Routing to accept any character in URL in Asp.net MVC like stackoverflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created below route to accept any value in last parameter but it's not working.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "My Route", // Route name
    "Home/MyMethod/{LID}/{MID}/{JID}/{*Title}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "MyMethod" } 
);
```

I want to accept a route like

```
http://localhost:10537/Home/MyMethod/47518/QQEBH/T2776086/8758~!@#$%^*()-+=-HAMPDEN--DR-TAMPA-FL-33626
```

A working sample is stackoverflow itself.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695240/how-to-show-american-sign-language-hand-&*%3E%3C:signs-on-ios-keyboard-keys/28695997?noredirect=1#comment51236176_28695997
```

You can see in above URL, it's accepting `&*><:` etc symbols.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: How the routing engine interpret {LID}/{MID}/{JID}/{*Title} ?

Comment: it supposed to accept any value in Title parameter.

Comment: It will accept. But how those values will be passed to your action method?

Comment: you're asking this for your knowledge or for my knowledge?

Comment: If you have a method like public ActionResult MyMethod(string lid, string mid, string jid, string title)
        {
            return new ContentResult { Content = string.Format("lid {0}, mid {1}, jid {2}, title {3}", lid, mid, jid, title) }; //just to show on screen
        } - it just works fine, what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

After a search, I found the solution

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Ref:- [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client/6026291#6026291)